# when I try this code it returns me facebook network consist of just 4 nodes instead of 50

Tags: r

I am new to r and I am trying to get my facebook network and I am sure my network consist of more than 50 vertices,

here is the code that I am using:

```
fb_token<-"some token gotten from facebook graph api"
mat <- getNetwork(token=fb_token, format="adj.matrix")
library(igraph)
network <- graph.adjacency(mat, mode="undirected")
names<-V(network)$name
network<-network+vertex("your name")# add vertex named your name
len<-length(V(network)$name)-1
edges<-matrix(c(rep("your name", len), names), nc=2)
network<-network+edge(t(edges)) # add edges from your name to everyone
set.seed(13)
plot(network, layout=layout.kamada.kawai, vertex.color="green")# plot my ego-network
```

Now when I try this code it returns me facebook network consist of just 4 nodes and when I checked those vertices they are the one that are kinda connecting me to other networks but I am wondering why I can not get my whole network?

Comment: Can you show the result of `dput(mat)`?

Comment: which library do you use for **getNetwork** ?

Comment: dupt(mat) result is :structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Bruce Spencer", "Pooria Mdn", "Dayal Dilli", 
"Shah Ari"), c("Bruce Spencer", "Pooria Mdn", "Dayal Dilli", 
"Shah Ari")))